# Promise looping dynamically

Tags: promise

How to loop this code dynamically and get final response so that the response will be sent to another promise

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 1

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // (*)
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2), 1000);
  });

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  alert(result); // 2

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2), 1000);
  });

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 4

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const EXIT_VALUE = null
    const MAX_RESULT = 40

    function delay(value, func){
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(()=> resolve(func(value)), 1000))
    }

    function cascade(value, func){
        return delay(value, func)
            .then(result => {
                if (result !== EXIT_VALUE) {
                    return cascade(result, func)
                }
            })
    }

    function done(result){
        console.log('final result:', result)
        return EXIT_VALUE
        // or even
        // return Promise.resolve(EXIT_VALUE)
    }

    cascade(1, value => {
        console.log(value)
        let result = value*2
        if (result>MAX_RESULT){
            return done(result)
        }
        return result
    })

    // outputs (every second): 
    1
    2
    4
    6
    8
    16
    32
    final result: 64
```